# wifi problem with android

Tags: wi-fi, ip-address

Hey all this might not be some programming problem rather a usability problem. I am new to android world. I have bought an android mobile [Samsung Galaxy Pro B7510] couple of days ago. I am trying to connect it to internet with wi-fi connection. But the problem is that normally when i connect my laptop to that router i need to repair the connection to get proper ip address like 192.168.1.2 etc. other wise i got 10.38.132.90 or rather something like this. And in that case i can't access internet. That's why i normally repair the connection on pc.

I am also using this router's wi fi with nokia E5 mobile and it gets proper ip address after 2 or 3 attemts (enabling and disabling wlan scanning)

But with android the ip address remains the invalid one i mean 10.38.132.90; not the correct one like 192.168.1.2 etc. So how can i repair or set static ip address with this phone.

Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This looks like a router misconfiguration issue than an Android problem. You will probably have more luck if you ask on [su].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use the "static IP settings":

1. Go to **Settings** -> **Wireless and network** -> **Wi-Fi settings**
2. Press menu button, select **Advanced**
3. Check **Use static IP**
4. Look for your PC's IP address, and enter a similar address for **IP address** (e.g. if your PC's one is 192.168.1.2, try 192.168.1.3).
5. Enter your router's IP as **Gateway** (usually 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.178.1 etc.)
6. Enter 255.255.255.0 as the **netmask**.

It is important that the IP address isn't already used in your network.

Comment: Perfect! You are a star :) I've been trying several ways of connecting to Wi-fi using tips but yours actually worked!